# Read file with javascript and send it to server

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-api, google-drive-api

I am using google drive api and I am trying the download a file from url, set it to variable and send it to backend. Please note that I use javascript picker of Google Drive.

Sidenote: *First I tried sending `id_token` and `fileId` to backend and tried accessing the file, but I couldn't authenticate the user with related scopes as user authenticated in the javascript not php.*

So I decided to get the file with axios and save it to a variable send post the file to my backend.

```
var downloadUrl = typeof file.exportLinks !== 'undefined' ? 
                file.exportLinks['application/pdf'] : file.webContentLink

axios.get(downloadUrl, {
          headers: {
              Authorization: 'bearer ' + gapi.client.getToken().access_token,
             'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
          }
 }).then(function (response) {
      console.log(response)
 }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
 });
```

I tried using this, but this throws

> Failed to load https://drive.google.com/uc?id=aba123bab23r24-m9_Mp4aiDcnibNf&export=download: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://deftfax.app' is therefore not allowed access.

Using axios, how can I download the file from url and set it to a variable?

Comment: Google won't allow this without getting permission from the user.  See https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The supported operations for downloading files using Drive API is already documented in [Download Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads):

Depending on the type of download you'd like to perform — a file, a Google Document, or a content link — you'll use one of the following URLs:

- Download a file — files.get with alt=media file resource
- Download and export a Google Doc — files.export
- Link a user to a file — webContentLink from the file resource

I myself can download an image file using Picker API by using the webcontentlink:

```
function downloadImage(data) {
      if (data.action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {

        var fileId = data.docs[0].id; 
        var webcontentlink = ' https://docs.google.com/uc?id='+fileId+'&export=download'

        window.open( webcontentlink,'image/png');
      }
}
```

Hope that get's you started with your implementation.

Comment: Yes, but at this point, I need to send it to my backend server to download the file, because as I used picker, the user is not actually authenticated in my backend, thus I can't download the file in my backend. Your method works, but I need to assign this file in a variable and send it to in a Post request. Is it possible to download the file with javascript in front-end and then send it to backend in a post just like 'file from file type input'?